# Automatically rename computers based on their MAC address

Tags: windows-7, automation, rename, mac-address, hostname

How to automatically rename a computer host / name based on it's MAC address?

I have 40 PC's and I need a script to rename them automatically at logon after I use ghost.
I'm in a Windows 7 environment.

Comment: Adding the operating system running on them might be a good idea.

Comment: Have you considered using DHCP?

Comment: I am using Linux server with Win clients. I use dhcp to assign ip basedd on each MAC. Can I use dhcp to configure Windows host name?

Comment: What should happen if the PCs have more than 1 MAC. There is a MAC for each network card thus computers may have more than one? You could get the MAC address(es) with the getmac command...

Answer (score -1):

This is quite an old (February 2009) article: [Script to change computer name based on MAC address](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/7bd23924-ec16-4d2d-9905-883beda454fd/script-to-change-compter-name-based-on-mac-address)

at Microsoft’s [Scripting forums](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/home?category=scripting).  I used it a couple of years ago.

```
Sub ChangeCompName(strComputer,Seg,IP)
'==============================================================================================
'This Sub Changes the Computer Name according to a Constant Value and the IP address entered
'It Changes the ComputerName key in the Registry and some other keys to do so
'==============================================================================================
const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002
Set oReg=GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" &_
 strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")

strKeyPath = "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ComputerName\ComputerName"
strValueName = "ComputerName"
strValue = "CompName" & seg & IP

oReg.SetStringValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,strKeyPath,strValueName,strValue


strKeyPath = "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters"
strValueName = "Hostname"
strValue = "CompName" & seg & IP

oReg.SetStringValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,strKeyPath,strValueName,strValue


strKeyPath = "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters"
strValueName = "NV Hostname"
strValue = "CompName" & seg & IP

oReg.SetStringValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,strKeyPath,strValueName,strValue


objFile.WriteLine "Computer Name: " & strValue
'==============================================================================================
'Write the new computer name to the Log
'==============================================================================================
End Sub
```

Comment: Note: As stated in the article (from which this script was copied) and in the comments in the script itself, this works with IP address (or at least it claims to), rather than MAC address as requested.  Worse, it appears to take the IP address as a parameter.  Can you explain how the OP would invoke this script, and how the invoking method could obtain the MAC address?